# Why is Azure database table reserved_page_count size much higher than actual data size?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Edit: I'd like to clarify my question and the motive for it.  This is not the only table we have like this.  At current growth rates, we'll soon hit the 250GB size limit for the S3 tier database.  If the database size reported what data is still visible in the table, we wouldn't worry about hitting that limit for a long, long time.  I'd like to know what is consuming all the space after the blobs have been set to null and if there is a way to mitigate the threat of hitting the database size limit.  Thanks.

I have a table in Azure Sql that has a few small fields and one varbinary(max) field (ImageBlob) that accounts for almost all of the bytes in each record.  After the data is uploaded from one client and stored in a record, it is downloaded by another client within a few minutes.  The varbinary field is set to null either after it is downloaded by the second client or later that night by a maintenance procedure.

When I look at system stat reserved_page_count, it is disproportionately larger than the actual size of data in the records.  Here is a copy of a query I'm using and its results.

```
SELECT sys.objects.name [Name]
, format(SUM(row_count), 'N0') [RowCount]
, format(ROUND(SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024, 0), 'N0') AS 'TableSizeMB'
, (select format(sum(datalength(ImageBlob) / 1024.0 / 1024.0), 'N0') from dbo.tblJobImages with(nolock)) as SumDatalengthImageBlobMB
, (select format( sum(BlobSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0), 'N0' ) from dbo.tblJobImages with(nolock)) as SumBlobSizeMB
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats with(nolock), sys.objects with(nolock)
WHERE sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id and sys.objects.name = 'tblJobImages'
GROUP BY sys.objects.name
```

produces these results:

> Name--------------RowCount---TableSizeMB---SumDatalengthImageBlobMB---SumBlobSizeMB
>
> tblJobImages---77,820---------57,320-------------579----------------------------------------37,670

This difference is having a significant impact on the overall database size being reported by Azure.  Why this difference?  Is there anything I can do about it?

Edit: modified the query for some more detail

```
SELECT sys.objects.name [Name]
, format(SUM(row_count), 'N0') [RowCount]
, format(ROUND(SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024, 0), 'N0') AS 'reserved_page_count'
, format(ROUND(SUM(in_row_used_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024, 0), 'N0') AS 'in_row_used_page_count'
, format(ROUND(SUM(lob_used_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024, 0), 'N0') AS 'lob_used_page_count'
, format(ROUND(SUM(row_overflow_used_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024, 0), 'N0') AS 'row_overflow_used_page_count'
, (select format(sum(datalength(ImageBlob) / 1024.0 / 1024.0), 'N0') from dbo.tblJobImages with(nolock)) as SumDatalengthImageBlobMB
, (select format( sum(BlobSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0), 'N0' ) from dbo.tblJobImages with(nolock)) as SumBlobSizeMB
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats with(nolock), sys.objects with(nolock)
WHERE sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id and sys.objects.name = 'tblJobImages'
GROUP BY sys.objects.name
```

produces these results

[image]

Comment: According to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql the reserved_page_count is a calculated value, perhaps try querying the page count columns individually to identify which one is throwing off the numbers.

Comment: Jacob H Is that also what is throwing off the total database size reported by Azure?

Comment: I am not sure, just saying you could try querying those 3 columns (in_row_reserved_page_count, lob_reserved_page_count, row_overflow_reserved_page_count) individually and see if that gives you some more insight.

Comment: Lol, thanks but I don't have anymore insight.  Those numbers don't come close to adding up like I thought they would.  I'm not sure what the practical implications are for my original questions - why the difference and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining the issue better at [Azure SQL Database size growing out of control DBCC SHRINKDATABASE doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962309/azure-sql-database-size-growing-out-of-control-dbcc-shrinkdatabase-doesnt-work)

It was a Microsoft issue involving ghost records.

Answer (score 0):

Per the discussion here [Why is Azure database table reserved_page_count size much higher than actual data size?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d2600131-7989-4bc6-85ff-012d1b8dd9d9/why-is-azure-database-table-reservedpagecount-size-much-higher-than-actual-data-size?forum=ssdsgetstarted%22Why%20is%20Azure%20database%20table%20reserved_page_count%20size%20much%20higher%20than%20actual%20data%20size?%22)

used_page_count would have been a better indicator than reserved_page_count but I still don't have a good answer for the difference between the sum of used_page_count and the size Azure Portal is reporting.

Azure SQL supports DBCC SHRINKDATABASE and running this weekly is looking like the best option I have available.